# Web Forms Model Binding CheckBoxList preselected on load

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding, checkboxlist

I have a checkbox list that I want to populate and perhaps I could use the page_load and do the job from there, right?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   //...
   var query = logic.GetPlanCoverages(planName);
   cbl_MemberCoverages.DataSource = coverages;
   cbl_MemberCoverages.DataBind();
}
```

But because Asp.Net has introduced Model Binding, now I can have this:

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cbl_MemberCoverages" 
 SelectMethod="BindMemberCoverages" DataTextField="CoverageName" DataValueField="CoverageCode">
 </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
public IEnumerable<PlanCoveragesDomainModel> BindMemberCoverages()
{            
   var planName = logic.GetShortPlanName();
   var query = logic.GetPlanCoverages(planName);
   return query;   
}
```

BUT... There is something I still don't like in Model Binding, or perhaps it's just me that cannot work out how to use it properly when you have to prepopulate a form.

A typical scenario is when from a list of users, I want to edit one. I open a new page and I have this form with lots of fields to populate. Perhaps one of the users has already assigned some of these coverages. But at the moment, the only workaround I found is:

```
public IEnumerable<PlanCoveragesDomainModel> BindMemberCoverages([QueryString]string mode)
    {
        if (!"edit".Equals(mode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            var planName = logic.GetShortPlanName();
            var query = logic.GetPlanCoverages(planName);
            return query;
        }

        var coverages = logic.GetPlanCoverages(CurrentModel.PlanName).Select(c => new ListItem(c.CoverageName, c.CoverageCode)).ToArray();
        cbl_MemberCoverages.Items.AddRange(coverages);
        cbl_MemberCoverages.DataSource = coverages;
        cbl_MemberCoverages.DataBind();

        foreach (ListItem listItem in cbl_MemberCoverages.Items)
        {
            listItem.Selected = CurrentModel.Coverages.Any(c => c.Value == listItem.Value);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Guys, any ideas?

Comment: You want to edit a user with model binding, but have another user's values pre-populated in the form?  This seems contrary to the idea of model binding in the first place, but it might be easier to prepopulate the data of the user object before you bind it to the controls.

Comment: Let me see if I understand ... what you want, is that after clicking 'edit' and going to the editing page, do you want the 'MemberCoverage' selected on the navigation page to appear selected on the editing page?

Comment: [Henryk Budzinski] Exactly what I meant :)

Comment: @Seano666 Why does this seem contrary? It's actually a pretty common use. If you want to edit an object, you want to see that object in its state. Therefore, the model represents the object that you want to edit, and you must show it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `OnDataBound` event for your CheckBoxList control.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cbl_MemberCoverages" 
    SelectMethod="BindMemberCoverages" DataTextField="CoverageName" 
    DataValueField="CoverageCode"
    OnDataBound="cblMemberCoverages_DataBound">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code

```
protected void cblMemberCoverages_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chkBoxList = sender as CheckBoxList;
    var item = chkbox.Items.FindByValue(queryStringCoverageCode);
    if(item != null)
        item.Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why I excluded the Databound event. Thank you :)